# Accessing anchor attributes and event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, preventdefault

I want to capture link clicks and store in my database without using a turnstile.  Current code

```
$( ".ads-box a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  var id = $(this).find('a').attr('id')
  console.log(href);
  console.log(id);
  console.log(this);
});
```

and

```
<div class="ads-box" id="adbox-35"><a href="http://www.makeitrightnola.org" id="ad-35" target="_blank"><img src="/g/shows/sidebar/83172823_ad_image.png" alt="Make It Right"></a></div>
```

Produces in console

```
undefined
undefined
<a href="http://www.makeitrightnola.org" id="ad-35" target="_blank"><img src="/g/shows/sidebar/83172823_ad_image.png" alt="Make It Right"></a>
```

How do I access the link's attributes?  What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.find('a')` in `var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');`. You are already click"ing" on a `<a>` element so it is enough with `$(this).attr('href');`

Try this:

```
$( ".ads-box a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = this.href;  // i used vanilla JS here
  var id = this.id;      // i used vanilla JS here
  console.log(href);
  console.log(id);
  console.log(this);
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a4YZe/)

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes just a little slow on the uptake here.